# Java swing : return value when button clicked

Tags: java, swing, button, return, actionlistener

I'm trying to create a method containing a button "generate" that allows you to return a value (character string or whatever) to the calling class of method whenever I click on the button.
I tried to do like this:

```
//start methode in "Generator" Class
public String start()
{
 String format = new String("");

        this.generateBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public String actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {  
            //after doing operations on "format" string

                    return format;
        }

    });
```

and I called start method from another class this way :

```
Generator genDialog =new Generator();
String format = genDialog.start();
```

I got this error in the Generator Class :

**The return type is incompatible with ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)**

How can I achieve what I want to do ?
I need I get a value of the class that I called when I clicked on a button inside.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  What if the user never clicks?  You want something like a promise.

Comment: Simply create a method that returns a `String` and call this method from inside the `actionPerformed()` method :-) You can not change the signatures of the `actionPerformed()` method, it is a method of an interface, which you have to __define__, while implementing the interface, to abide with the contract :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your Generator class is a dialog.  If it is a modal dialog the setVisible(true) method will block until the dialog gets hidden.  So what your generateBtn action listener should do is store the generated string in a member variable and then call setVisible(false).  Your start method then sets the calls setVisible(true) and returns the value.

It would look something like this.

```
 public class Generator  extends JDialog {
    private String format;
    private JButton generateBtn;

    public Generator () {
        setModal(true);
        generateBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // create format string
                setVisible(false);
            }
         });
    }

    public String start() {
        setVisible(true);
        return format;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `actionPerformed()` return a String...And I don't see a reason why you would need to.  I think you can perform whatever operations are needed on `format` inside of `actionPerformed()`.